Neo4jError: Neo.TransientError.General.DatabaseUnavailable (Unable to get a routing table for database 'graph5' because this database is unavailable)
In golang sdk environment,I'm trying to create a new neo4j database and use it to import data. the golang code is following.

        graphName := fmt.Sprintf("graph%d", originid)
        //创建一个neo4j数据库
        o.Originid = originid
        rootSession := l.svcCtx.Neo4jConn.NewSession(l.ctx, neo4j.SessionConfig{})
        _, err = rootSession.Run(l.ctx, fmt.Sprintf("create database %s", graphName), nil)
        if err != nil {
            l.Error("创建数据库失败", req, err.Error())
            return &types.Response{
                Status:  false,
                Message: "创建失败",
            }, nil
        }
        rootSession.Close(l.ctx)
        //获取新的数据库会话来制图
        cursession := l.svcCtx.Neo4jConn.NewSession(l.ctx, neo4j.SessionConfig{
            DatabaseName: graphName,
        })
        defer cursession.Close(l.ctx)
        defer func() {
            if err != nil || !resp.Status {
                cursession.Run(l.ctx, fmt.Sprintf("drop database %d", originid), nil)
            }
        }()
        for i := 0; i < len(path); i++ {
            if err := l.svcCtx.Generator.Generate(l.ctx, strconv.Itoa(int(ownerid)), path[i], nodeName, relationshipName, cursession); err != nil {
                l.Error("生成图失败", req, err.Error())
                return &types.Response{
                    Status:  false,
                    Message: "创建失败",
                }, nil
            }
        }


Result
the database has created successfully,but cant init data to the new database,but i can pass cypher-shell to connect the new database。
How can I solve this problem?
input
graphName: graph4
Result
cypher-shell result
server console:
kibana discover
